# Python Django psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm am the following code in my pycharm console, my date is length is clearly less than the mentioned field size, then why this error

my code

```
df=pd.read_csv('/home/asif/Documents/Projects/TaxVisor/legal.txt',header=None,names=['type'])


for type in df['type']:
...     print(type)
...     print(len(type))
...     LegalElement.objects.create(type=df['type'])
```

My model:

class LegalElement(models.Model):
type = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)

my data(from CSV)

```
PTY LTD
PTY. LTD
PTY. LIMITED
PTY. LTD.
PTY LTD.
PTY LIMITED
PROPRIETARY LTD.
PROPRIETARY LTD
PROPRIETARY LIMITED
```

My DB

```
create table company_registration_legalelement
(
    id   serial      not null
        constraint company_registration_legalelement_pkey
            primary key,
    type varchar(25) not null
);
```

my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asif/DevProjects/taxvisor/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(25)
```

Comment: Can you show the output for the ```for type in df['type']:``` snippet? Also is that the complete CSV data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data has exceeded the max_length=25 value. Instead if using models.CharField. Please use models.TextField. It can handle any length of character body.
[Doc for models.TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)

### Code

Your code should be

```
class LegalElement(models.Model): 
        type = models.TextField(null=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will not solve the issue. The database table has varchar(25), so stuffing more into the model will not work when the data gets to the table.